# The POST method is not supported for this route en ventana modal

Tags: laravel, formularios, rutas

Tengo un problema bastante extraño: tengo una ventana modal en la cual hay un formulario, tengo la ruta POST para poder guardar los datos de este formulario en la base de datos, pero cuando envío el form me dice que *el método post no es soportado por la ruta...*

Así tengo declarada la ruta:

```
Route::post('material/bodega/seriado', [BodegaLogisticaController::class, 'insertExcel']);
```

El Modal con el formulario lo tengo así:

```
 <!--MODAL CAGRA DE ARCHIVO DE SERIES-->
  <div class="modal fade" id="modal-seriado-{{$item->ingreso_material_material_nom->id}}" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Asignación de Series a Material ID: {{$item->ingreso_material_material_nom->id}}</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
           <form action="{{url('material/bodega/seriado')}}" method="post">
            @csrf

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="serie">Seleccione Archivo de series</label>
                <input type="file" name="serie" id="serie" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-md" type="submit">Cargar Archivo</button>
           </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

He limpiado y cacheado las rutas `php artisan route:clear`, `route:cache` y nada que funciona.

Saludos.

Comment: Tienes alguna ruta con un nombre parecido?

Comment: no, ninguna ruta similar

Comment: @BetaM Volvi a crear la ruta pero nada, viendo la consola en chrome veo que me muestra: 405 method not allowed

Answer (score 0):

Ejecuta: `php artisan r:l` y verifica que no tengas ninguna ruta similar.

Si no se me ocurre que hagas la ruta:

```
Route::get('material/bodega/seriado', [BodegaLogisticaController::class, 'insertExcel']);
```

Y en el form:

```
<form action="{{url('material/bodega/seriado')}}" method="GET">
                    @csrf
                    @method('POST')
```